# React Native WebView - Vimeo url not loading images

Tags: react-native, image, video, webview

I am loading a Vimeo video using WebView in ReactNative. However, the images do not load (badge and pre-play image). I am using react-native@0.70.5 and react-native-webview@11.23.1, below is the code for my WebView, and screenshots of the video in the emulator vs. directly accessed over the browser url bar.

```
<WebView
  allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
  source={{ uri: "https://player.vimeo.com/video/65107797" }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  originWhitelist={["*"]}
  style={{ height: 300 }}
/>
```

Screenshot of video in iOS emulator:
[image: Screenshot of video in iOS emulator]

Screenshot of video in the browser:
[image: Screenshot of video in the browser]

Comment: Are you getting any error on onError or onHttpError?

Comment: No, I'm logging in both of those handlers, and I don't see anything in the terminal.